# ¿Cómo separar 2 string con el metodo .split() y regex sin borrar los símbolos que se tomaron en cuenta para dicha separación?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, split

Debo reordenar los idiomas de este txt, ya que cada línea está constituida por la siguiente estructura:
`english\tspanish\n`

and it should stay:
`spanish\tenglish\n`

Aquí hay un fragmento del archivo .txt original:

```
Do you still watch TV sometimes?    ¿Sigues viendo la televisión a veces?
Let's go!.  ¡vamos!.
I sometimes watch TV.   a veces miro la television.
I sort of understand.   en cierto modo entiendo.
I started this topic.   abri este tema.
I started this topic.   abri este topico.
I still don't get it.   todavia no puedo capturar.
I still don't get it.   todavia no me apodere.
I studied last night.   estudie anoche.
I suddenly feel sick.   me siento enfermo.
```

Y usando este código, logré ordenarlo de la siguiente manera:

```py
import re

input_file = "eng-french.txt"
output_file = "reordered_languages_files.txt"

with open(input_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
    with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as write_file:
        for line in read_file:
            print(repr(line))

            n_sense_input = re.split(r'[.!?][.!?"]?\s+', line)[0]
            n_sense_ouput = re.split(r'[.!?][.!?"]?\s+', line)[1]

            line = str(n_sense_ouput) + "\t" + str(n_sense_input) + "\n"

            print(repr(line))

            write_file.write(line) #Escribe la linea traducida
```

Reordenando el texto, pero esta expresión regular está omitiendo algunos símbolos importantes `.` , `?`, `!`.

```
¿Sigues viendo la televisión a veces    Do you still watch TV sometimes
¡vamos  Let's go
a veces miro la television  I sometimes watch TV
entiendo en poco bonito I sort of understand
abri este tema  I started this topic
todavia no puedo capturar   I still don't get it
todavia no me apodere   I still don't get it
estudie anoche  I studied last night
me siento enfermo   I suddenly feel sick
```

Esto se debe a que la expresión regular `'[.!?][.!?"]?\s+'`, Esto se debe a que la expresión regular divide la cadena en función de esos símbolos, pero ahora la necesitaría para dividir la cadena sin eliminarlos.

Si esto funciona bien, el texto reordenado debería verse así:

```
¿Sigues viendo la televisión a veces?   Do you still watch TV sometimes?
¡vamos!.    Let's go!.
a veces miro la television. I sometimes watch TV.
en cierto modo entiendo.    I sort of understand.
abri este tema. I started this topic.
abri este topico.   I started this topic.
todavia no puedo capturar.  I still don't get it.
todavia no me apodere.  I still don't get it.
estudie anoche. I studied last night.
me siento enfermo.  I suddenly feel sick.
```

Básicamente las mismas oraciones separadas por tabulaciones, pero reordenadas el contenido antes y después de la `\t`.

Y deben ser como en este ejemplo, es decir, incluyendo los respectivos símbolos.

Comment: Te has equivocado de sitio, este es el **español** :-)

Comment: @masterguru Lo siento realmente, ahi la tradusco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según indicas, las frases están separadas con tabuladores, por lo que basta con

```
ingles, castellano = linea.split("\t")
```

para dividir la línea en dos por el tabulador. Luego sólo tienes que grabar en el orden deseado.

#### Demo

```
frases = [
"Do you still watch TV sometimes?\t¿Sigues viendo la televisión a veces?",
"Let's go!.\t¡vamos!.",
"I sometimes watch TV.\ta veces miro la television.",
"I sort of understand.\ten cierto modo entiendo.",
"I started this topic.\tabri este tema.",
"I started this topic.\tabri este topico.",
"I still don't get it.\ttodavia no puedo capturar.",
"I still don't get it.\ttodavia no me apodere.",
"I studied last night.\testudie anoche.",
"I suddenly feel sick.\tme siento enfermo."]

for linea in frases:
    ingles, castellano = linea.split("\t")
    print(f"{castellano}\t{ingles}")
```

produce:

```
¿Sigues viendo la televisión a veces?   Do you still watch TV sometimes?
¡vamos!.    Let's go!.
a veces miro la television. I sometimes watch TV.
en cierto modo entiendo.    I sort of understand.
abri este tema. I started this topic.
abri este topico.   I started this topic.
todavia no puedo capturar.  I still don't get it.
todavia no me apodere.  I still don't get it.
estudie anoche. I studied last night.
me siento enfermo.  I suddenly feel sick.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Luego la adaptas para leer las frases desde un archivo y grabarlas en otro, lo que no tiene dificultad para ti.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @zRainBow Si la respuesta te ha sido de utilidad acéptala, asi ayudas a la comunidad a no tener preguntas abiertas

Comment: @multiple listo ;)